# Android, C/C++ memory crash doesn't happen in Eclipse Java debugger

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I am investigating an Android C++ code crash, Fatal signal 11, happens when a series of actions are taken in a loop for about 4~7 times, randomly happens, but always with a **GC_FOR_ALLOC free** precede. The problem disappears if I run the app in Eclipse Java debugger, but right after unplug usb cable it occurs again. The issue happens in Eclipse Native App debugger and of course happens when running by itself. The C++ library used is huge and very complicated, the .so was built from 10s of .a files. Tried to increase heap size but no help. The problem might be multiple release of memory, or trying to use memory that was released. Bidirectional JNI calls are used. C++ lib was built with debug info, Eclipse native app debugger does stop when the crash happens but the call stack doesn't show useful info to locate the issue. Any suggestion is really appreciated as I have been on this issues for weeks.

[image: Eclipse ADT Native App Debugger]

```
========================================================================
03-13 16:27:58.879: D/dalvikvm(4404): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 788K, 25% free 12412K/16352K, paused 36ms, total 36ms
03-13 16:27:58.889: A/libc(4404): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xfffffe04 (code=1), thread 4425 (FinalizerDaemon)

========================================================================
03-13 16:27:59.734: I/dumpstate(4815): begin
03-13 16:27:59.734: I/dumpstate(4815): dumpstate is still running
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698): Build: samsung/v1awifiue/v1awifi:4.4.2/KOT49H/P900UEU1ANAE:user/release-keys
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698): Hardware: universal5420
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698): Revision: 9
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698): Bootloader: P900UEU1ANAE
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698): Radio: unknown
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698): Kernel: Linux version 3.4.39-448792 (dpi@SWDD5820) (gcc version 4.6.x-google 20120106 (prerelease) (GCC) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jan 21 09:47:41 KST 2014
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/v1awifiue/v1awifi:4.4.2/KOT49H/P900UEU1ANAE:user/release-keys'
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698): Revision: '9'
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698): pid: 4404, tid: 4425, name: FinalizerDaemon  >>> com.abc.android <<<
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr fffffe04
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):     r0 fffffe04  r1 00000000  r2 ffffffff  r3 fffffe04
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):     r4 fffffe00  r5 72376008  r6 00000000  r7 725b7f6c
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):     r8 77db4b10  r9 725b7f64  sl 72376018  fp 77db4b24
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):     ip 405fcb58  sp 77db4af8  lr 404d3027  pc 400ab568  cpsr 800f0010
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):     d0  79e6e93879d737b8  d1  7c8d15987a6ac35d
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):     d2  7c8be1287a4fd7ea  d3  79e82db07a034079
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):     d4  8000000000000000  d5  0000000000000000
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):     d6  4b2e3f2000004000  d7  42c8000000000001
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):     d16 8000000000000000  d17 0000000000000000
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):     d18 0000000000000000  d19 0000000000000001
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):     d20 0000000000004000  d21 0000000000000000
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):     d22 0000000000004000  d23 0000000000000001
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):     d24 0000000000000000  d25 4008000000000000
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):     d26 3fc2f112df3e5244  d27 0000000000000001
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):     d28 00000000000000e6  d29 00000000000000e5
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):     d30 0000000000000001  d31 0000000000004000
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):     scr 80000010
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698): backtrace:
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):     #00  pc 00003568  /system/lib/libcutils.so (android_atomic_dec+12)
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):     #01  pc 0008e023  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkPixelRef::globalUnref()+6)
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):     #02  pc 000b4675  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkPaint::~SkPaint()+56)
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):     #03  pc 0007ed87  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):     #04  pc 0001e80c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):     #05  pc 0004f24b  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):     #06  pc 00027c20  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):     #07  pc 0002ec5c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):     #08  pc 0002c2c0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):     #09  pc 00061759  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):     #10  pc 0006177d  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):     #11  pc 0005646b  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):     #12  pc 0000d280  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):     #13  pc 0000d418  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698): stack:
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):          77db4ab8  00000002  
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):          77db4abc  77db4ad4  [stack:4425]
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):          77db4ac0  7915a888  
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):          77db4ac4  72376008  
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):          77db4ac8  fffffeac  
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):          77db4acc  41701594  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-zygote (deleted)
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):          77db4ad0  41701590  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-zygote (deleted)
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):          77db4ad4  41608958  
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):          77db4ad8  416c3c68  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):          77db4adc  4165dc2d  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):          77db4ae0  00000000  
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):          77db4ae4  79e765b8  
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):          77db4ae8  77db4b10  [stack:4425]
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):          77db4aec  416c8a80  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):          77db4af0  40104000  /system/lib/libc.so
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):          77db4af4  40108384  
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):     #00  77db4af8  79ea52c0  
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):          ........  ........
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):     #01  77db4af8  79ea52c0  
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):          77db4afc  404f9679  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkPaint::~SkPaint()+60)
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):     #02  77db4b00  79ea52c0  
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):          77db4b04  40205d8b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):     #03  77db4b08  6d604c48  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):          77db4b0c  41628810  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+116)
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):     #04  77db4b10  725b7f64  
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):          77db4b14  00000001  
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):          77db4b18  00000008  
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):          77db4b1c  41711348  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-zygote (deleted)
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):          77db4b20  421b7a78  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698):          77db4b24  4165924f  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIM
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698): processName:com.abc.android
03-13 16:27:59.744: D/CrashAnrDetector(2698): broadcastEvent : com.abc.android SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE
```

Comment: Have you tried to compile everything with `-O0 -g` so you can see the stack?

Comment: This isn't really something that's easy to debug.  It looks like either C++ is referencing Java heap memory after its no longer valid, or vice versa.  The address is very high and doesn't look like a random address.  My guess would be C overwrote a no longer valid memory address that Java thought it owned and was storing using as a pointer in its free list.

Comment: FWIW, the following issue reported four days ago may be related: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53021

Comment: Thank you all for the ideas. Any explanation why it's OK in Eclipse Java debugger?

Comment: The issue is in a C++ lib, some code for other platform was called by mistake. No tool gives me direct help to locate the issue. Thanks.